# Trouble centering photo on mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've put together a basic memorial page on Wordpress using this theme - https://github.com/auniverseaway/rememberingjeff

But I'm having trouble centering a photo on both mobile and desktop. It seems like it shows up further right than it's supposed to on mobile, and further left on desktop.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nick's image is styled with `class="size-full wp-image-13 aligncenter"`

Unfortunately, `aligncenter` is not set in your css.

Example from 2016 theme:

```
.aligncenter {
   clear: both;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto 1.75em;
}
```

Sorry for your loss.

Answer (score 0):

```
.post img {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Added, but it didn't change anything from what I'm seeing. Could it be because my link is page, not a post?

Comment: Inspect that element, I don't see your css going through. You can also target #post-2 > img